# Why Bootstrap sass gem lazy loads icon fonts in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I have noticed that in my app, where I am using the `bootstrap-sass` gem to integrate bootstrap, it make a request for the font when I need a glyphicon.

Basically, the icon appear few seconds later because it has to retrieve it from the server. How can I avoid this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Bootstrap, Sass, Ruby, or Rails.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't really avoid it but you can make it faster so that it is less noticeable by using a CDN (Content Delivery Network) or serving your assets from an s3 bucket. This is assuming you are already taking advantage of the asset pipeline. If not i would try that first.

Asset Pipeline:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

How to serve assets from s3:
https://firmhouse.com/blog/complete-guide-to-serving-your-rails-assets-over-s3-with-asset_sync/